# CSS3 Firefox Border Radius Clip

Tags: html, css

i am not sure why the Firefox browser adding pixellete border radius on right corner. If anyone notice it in the image i attached.

this is only happening in Firefox browser. Is there a way to fix it?

HTML and CSS:

```css
    nav {
        height:50px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    nav > ul {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 144.429px;
         background-color: rgb(128, 0, 128);
        border-color: rgb(255, 167, 252);
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    
    nav > ul > li:first-child {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
        border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li:last-child {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
        border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    }
```

```html
<nav class=""id="menusystem">
        <ul><li class="active"><span><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Home</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Book Now</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Service Prices</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-th"></i> Product Prices</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Our Testimonials</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Our Events</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact Us</span></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/1v2p1f3c/) of your source, but I don't see the problem you're describing. What version of the browser and/or OS are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem to. Take a look in the webconsole of firefox and look if there are any errors. A blue error is a css error. maybe did you forget a prefix or something but I don't see a problem in your code

Comment: im not quite sure as well, if i reduced the width it fixes the issue, sometimes when make it wider, than it happens .. strange!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```css
nav {
            height: 50px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 1012px;
        }
        nav > ul {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        nav > ul > li {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            line-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 144.429px;
             background-color: rgb(128, 0, 128);
            border-color: rgb(255, 167, 252);
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
        nav > ul > li:first-child {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
            border-top-left-radius: 25px;
        }
        nav > ul > li:last-child {
            border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
            border-top-right-radius: 25px;
        }
```

```html
    <nav class=""id="menusystem">
        <ul><li class="active"><span><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Home</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Book Now</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Service Prices</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-th"></i> Product Prices</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Our Testimonials</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Our Events</span></li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact Us</span></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```